# Convert Sheets As Separate PDFs w/ Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for feedback on my code. It is currently working in my test environment and I wanted to see if anyone could find any flaws in the code that may cause trouble for the user.

The purpose of this code is, to convert each sheet as its own `.PDF` and have it saved down in a folder for a given condition. I'm first prompted where I want to save the `.PDF`s then, I use an if function to scan cell `A1` (I plan on changing this in the future) for an email address. These will be the sheets I want to convert.

I've added  a fail safe so previous `.PDF`s can't be overwritten without the user knowing. Once all applicable sheets are converted, it's finished.

```
Sub SaveSheetsAsPDF()
    Dim DestFolder As String
    Dim PDFFile As String
    Dim wb As Worksheet
    Dim AlwaysOverwritePDF As Boolean

    'Speed up macro
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Prompt for file destination
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = True Then
            DestFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & _
                vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, _
                "Must Specify Destination Folder"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    'Create new PDF file name including path and file extension
    For Each wb In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Test A1 for a mail address
        If wb.Range("A1").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
            PDFFile = DestFolder & Application.PathSeparator & wb.Name & _
                "-" & Format(Date, "mmyy") & ".pdf"
            'If the PDF already exists
            If Len(Dir(PDFFile)) > 0 Then
                If AlwaysOverwritePDF = False Then
                    OverwritePDF = MsgBox(PDFFile & " already exists." & _
                        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
                        vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
                    On Error Resume Next
                    'If you want to overwrite file then delete current one
                    If OverwritePDF = vbYes Then
                        Kill PDFFile
                    Else
                        MsgBox "OK then, if you don't overwrite the " & _
                            "existing PDF, I can't continue." & vbCrLf _
                            & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", _
                            vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Else
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Kill PDFFile
                End If
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make " & _
                        "sure the file is not open or write protected." _
                        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", _
                        vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        End If
        'Print PDF
        wb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next wb
    MsgBox "All Files Have Been Converted!"

ResetSettings:
    'Resets optimization settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are going to ask other people to look over your code; one thing that would be beneficial is learn to indent your code, Check this link out, [Excel VBA Indentation and Auto Indent](http://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-indentation-auto-indent/), Indenting makes code easier to read and debug.

Comment: if your code is already functioning then this is not the right place for this question. See the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.

Comment: This question is better suited to [**Stack Exchange Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I Appreciate the feedback, I'll make sure to refer to the code review in the future.

Comment: @iLL-Army Q's like yours asking for a review of code are _not_ off topic on SO (provided they meet other criteria) Please don't feel that you must move it to Code-Review. But if you do, please ensure you meet their Q requirements.

Comment: I tidied your indentation and spacing to make it easier for other to read your code.  My first suggestion is to add the line `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and then compile or run your code.  This will help prevent issues by helping ensure your variables and objects are declared and handled properly.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - Not to be argumentative but I just reviewed the on-topic list at [help/on-topic] and my interpretation is that there needs to be a *problem* with the code of some kind.  Do you disagree with my interpretation?

Comment: @ash debate is ok with me.  This issue has been specifically discussed on Meta.  I've seen posts from mods and SE employees (maybe even Shog, I'm on my phone atm so it's a bit hard to search out) specifically says what I said.  Also, migration from SO has been an issue for CR with a lot of rejects. I too reread the help, and see nothing banning review requests.

Comment: @ash and btw when I reviewed the OPs code there a a few issues/bugs that _might_ make it a bad fit for CR

Answer (score 1):

Issues I see here:

- The lack of resetting error handling after `On Error Resume Next`
- Readability will be vastly improved by indentation and removing excess white space
- Clutter.  Separating out the File Deletion makes the main logic flow clearer
- You might want to rethink the workflow.  Do you really want the user to get halfway through (and maybe have deleted *some* files) the exit?
- Undeclared variables.  Add Option Explicit to catch that

---

```
Option Explicit


Sub SaveSheetsAsPDF()
    Dim DestFolder As String
    Dim PDFFile As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet  '<~~ use a more meaningful name
    Dim AlwaysOverwritePDF As Boolean
    Dim FileDate As String

    'Speed up macro
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Prompt for file destination
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = True Then
            DestFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator '<~~ avoids repeating some logic
        Else
            MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & _
              vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
              "Press OK to exit this macro.", _
              vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    'Create new PDF file name including path and file extension
    FileDate = "-" & Format(Date, "mmyy") & ".pdf" '<~~ avoids repeating some logic
    AlwaysOverwritePDF = False '<~~~~ or True, or prompt the user, up to you

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Test A1 for a mail address
        If ws.Range("A1").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then '<~~ may not be fully robust
            PDFFile = DestFolder & ws.Name & FileDate

            'If the PDF already exists
            If CheckDeleteFile(PDFFile, AlwaysOverwritePDF) Then
                'PDF doesn't exist (any more)

                'Prints PDF
                '<~~~~ probably want this inside the If email
                ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                  Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                  Filename:=PDFFile, _
                  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                  IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                  OpenAfterPublish:=False
            Else
                ' Sheet was skipped, what now?
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    MsgBox "All Files Have Been Converted!"

ResetSettings:
    'Resets optimization settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
EH:
    MsgBox "Unexpected Error", Err.Description
    'Add any error handling here
    Resume ResetSettings
End Sub
```